# electron-builder skipped macOS application code signing, reason=cannot find valid "Apple Distribution" identity

Tags: macos, ssl, electron, ssl-certificate, electron-builder

I am trying to run the command `electron-builder build --mac` so that my electron app will build and sign a mac apple store (mas) build. But it keeps failing with this error:

```
> electron-builder build --mac

  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13 os=20.3.0
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=mas arch=x64 electron=10.4.7 appOutDir=dist/mas
  • signing         file=dist/mas/RenderTune.app identityName=Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (123123123) identityHash=abcabcabcbabacbacb8 provisioningProfile=none
  ⨯ skipped macOS application code signing  reason=cannot find valid "Apple Distribution" identity, see https://electron.build/code-signing allIdentities=  1) abcabcabcbabacbacb8 "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  2) abcabcabcbabacbacb1 "Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  3) abcabcabcbabacbacb2 "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  4) abcabcabcbabacbacb3 "Mac Developer: Martin Barker (CFDL3PKQB3)"
  5) abcabcabcbabacbacb4 "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  6) abcabcabcbabacbacb5 "Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  7) abcabcabcbabacbacb6 "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  8) abcabcabcbabacbacb7 "com.apple.kerberos.kdc" (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED)
     8 identities found
                                            Valid identities only
  1) abcabcabcbabacbacb8 "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  2) abcabcabcbabacbacb1 "Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  3) abcabcabcbabacbacb2 "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  4) abcabcabcbabacbacb3 "Mac Developer: Martin Barker (CFDL3PKQB3)"
  5) abcabcabcbabacbacb4 "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  6) abcabcabcbabacbacb5 "Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (123123123)"
  7) abcabcabcbabacbacb6 "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (123123123)"
     7 valid identities found  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: skipped ...
```

The frustrating part is that I have a folder, `rendertune1.2.0` which is an electron project on my same laptop that when i run electron-builder --mac, it works and signs perfectly. But when I try with my new folder `electron-builder-react`, i get the above error.

I've tried to structure the projects to be identical, including an identical package.json file with identical build:{} params, ive even tried running two commands:

```
$ security find-identity -vp codesigning
$ certtool y | grep Developer\ I
```

Which show you in the terminal some certificate info:

```
Martins-MacBook-Air:rendertunev1.2.0 martinbarker$ security find-identity -vp codesigning
  1) 123123123 "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (78787878)"
  2) xxxxx "Mac Developer: Martin Barker (CFDL3PKQB3)"
  3) zzzz "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Martin Barker (78787878)"
  4) yyyy "Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (78787878)"
     4 valid identities found
Martins-MacBook-Air:rendertunev1.2.0 martinbarker$ certtool y | grep Developer\ I
   Common Name     : Developer ID Certification Authority
   Common Name     : Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (78787878)
   Common Name     : Developer ID Certification Authority
   Common Name     : Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (78787878)
   Common Name     : 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Martin Barker (78787878)
   Common Name     : Developer ID Certification Authority
   Common Name     : Developer ID Installer: Martin Barker (78787878)
   Common Name     : Developer ID Certification Authority
   Common Name     : Developer ID Application: Martin Barker (78787878)
   Common Name     : Developer ID Certification Authority
```

The results of these commands are identical no matter which repo/folder I run them in.

So I am not sure which certificate I am missing that is causing this electron-builder error? The error log states

```
skipped macOS application code signing  reason=cannot find valid "Apple Distribution" identity
```

But I have not found a download for any "Apple Distribution" certificate file on the apple developer website, and my other repo builds perfectly fine which you think would mean I have all my necessary mac certificates?

Answer (score -1):

solved by running react-scripts build